# How to bind Gridview when performing union on two database and applying some conditions on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

I have an table name dbo.EmpInfo having 4 columns

```
1-UserId 2-SubUserId 3-Year 4-Status
```

I have an another table (in other database) name dbo.EmpInfo1 having 4 columns

```
1-UserId 2-SubUserId 3-Year 4-Status
```

UserId may be repeating in both tables..

Now i have to find those UserId from Both tables whose Status="Success" and this status count is < 10 and bind these values in Gridview..

for ex-I have an UserId say mayank@gmail.com and in dbo.EmpInfo it has status count=5(Status="Success") and in dbo.EmpInfo1 it has status count=7 so from both tables the total count for mayank@gmail.com is 12 so we have to bind this userId in Gridview. and Gridview having all the above columns..

i have a procedure -

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_countUserDetails]
as
begin try
begin transaction
Select distinct(UserId) from EmpInfo where Status='Success' 
union all
Select distinct(UserId) from MyDB.dbo.EmpInfo1 where Status='Sucess'
commit transaction
end try
```

in my .cs file i used

```
SqlDataReader dr = ms.sp_SelectExecuter("sp_countUserDetails");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    foreach (DataRow DR in dt.Rows)
    {
        ms = new MethodStore();
        ms.sp_SelectExecuter("sp_usercount", "@userid", (DR["UserId"]).ToString()); 
    }
```

and the Procedure is-

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_usercount]
@userid varchar(50)
as
declare @count1213 dec =0, @count1314 dec =0;
begin try
begin transaction
select @count1314= count(UserId) from EmpInfo where Status='Status' and      UserID=@userid;
select @count1213= count(UserId) from MyDB.dbo.EmpInfo1 where Status='Success' and UserID=@userid;
select @count1213+@count1314 as 'Count'
if((@count1213+@count1314)>=10)
insert into MyTaxCafe.dbo.demo values (@userid);
commit transaction
end try
```

bt the table dbo.demo doesn't contain distinct UserId..because our Procedure

```
[dbo].[sp_countUserDetails]
```

give Distinct values from both table but at due to Union there is an redundancy can we control it because Same UserId may be Exist in both tables

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: Your final output would have the same column names, so for gridview it would not matter. But to get the unique id for each row (since you said UserID may repeat in both tables) you would need to add ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) in the select statement to get unique ID for each row. To do this, you can dump the result in hashtable and then select from that table, and add the above mentioned line in that select.

Comment: @AbeMiessler-here is my code..

Answer (score 0):

First you need a SQL to query two database , you may try it like this

```
SELECT Status FROM [database1].[dbo].[TableName] AS t1 INNER JOIN [database2].[dbo].[TableName] AS t2
ON (t1.UserId = t2.UserId)
WHERE Status='Success'
GROUP BY Status
Having COUNT(Status) < 10
```

in your C# code , use SqlDataAdapter to fill DataTable, 
then set DataGridView's field DataSource  = DataTable

Comment: it gives only those results having same UserId but in my both tables UserIds may be Same or may be Different too..

Answer (score 0):

You must use union from your query to get expected result.
Your columns are same in both tables so u can use union without any changes
for example

```
select * (select * from TableName1
where Status = 'Success'

union

select * from TableName2
where Status = 'Success'
) A

where count(Status)<10
group by SubUserId, Year, Status
```

try this.